# Does the "What topics can I ask about here?" page need a minor edit

Tags: discussion

I feel the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page needs a minor edit. At present, this page still contains a link to the no-longer active blog (see screenshot below):

[image]

While linking to the blog itself is not necessarily a problem, I do feel it is a problem *within* this context. The reason being that the whole purpose of this paragraph is to help users understand the Q&A setting of Ask Different is best suited to questions about practical problems, rather than to *discussion* type questions. It then refers users to the chat room and blog if they have an opinion-based post (at least that's how I'm interpreting it).

I propose we remove the link so that this sentence now reads:

*We do have a [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com) for opinion-based posts.*

Or, something similar to the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed, thanks for spotting this.